# C# How to Moq entityframework DbSet Add method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, moq

I am trying to create a test to test entity framework `Add` method. Can anyone help how to mock the `DbSet.Add` method. I have tried as below but not working. What am I doing wrong?

The result I am getting is `null` after `repository.Insert`...

Test.cs:

```
var productToCreate = new Product { Name = "Added", Description = "Added" };        

var result = repository.InsertAsync(objToCreate, userContext).Result;
Assert.AreEqual(result.Name, "Added");
```

Mock.cs

```
internal static DbSet<T> GetMockedDataSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> data) where T : class
{
    // Create a mocked data set that contains the data
    var set = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
    set.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>>()
        .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
        .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>(data.GetEnumerator()));
    set.As<IQueryable<T>>()
        .Setup(m => m.Provider)
        .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(data.AsQueryable().Provider));
    set.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.AsQueryable().Expression);
    set.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.AsQueryable().ElementType);
    set.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

    set.Setup(x => x.AsNoTracking()).Returns(set.Object);
    set.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => data.Concat(new[] { s }));

    // Return the mock
    return set.Object;
}
```

Repository:

```
public async Task<Product> InsertAsync(Product input)
{
    using (var ctx = .....))
    {
        var added = ctx.Set<Product>().Add(input);

        await ctx.ValidateAndSaveAsync();

        return added;
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi, Sorry, I dont understand what do you mean? I have provided my code block and explained what i am expecting?. Thanks

Comment: This example is incomplete. too many dependent variables are unknown to be able to recreate the problem, the method under test is different to what was shown in the test, the setup shown is incomplete....need I go on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to how the `Add` method is being used in the method under test...

```
var added = ctx.Set<Product>().Add(input);
```

...there should also be a `Returns` in the setup that returns the argument that was entered, if that is the desired functionality.

```
set.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<T>()))
   .Returns<T>(arg => arg)
   .Callback<T>((s) => data.Concat(new[] { s }));
```

But given that the information about context dependency is unknown...

```
using (var ctx = .....))
```

It is uncertain if the provided solution will have the desired effect.

Additionally if testing an async method, don't mix async and sync calls. The following line...

```
var result = repository.InsertAsync(objToCreate, userContext).Result;
```

...can cause deadlocks.

Make the test method async all the way.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task InsertAsync_Should_Return_Product() {
    //...other code

    var expected = new Product { Name = "Added", Description = "Added" };        

    var actual = await repository.InsertAsync(expected, userContext);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected.Name, actual.Name);  
}
```

Comment: Wow! It worked like charm. thank you. I changed the testmethod to use async. thanks again

Comment: Side note - Your callback on the add method is not doing anything. it has no effect on the original collection provided.